# Link ArrayLists and save data on file

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working on a Java app for a school project where we have to enter user information: Name, Student ID and their points. How can I store all the data for each user on an ArrayList (or an Array or really whatever type) so I can keep track of all the data.

Example:

John Doe - 401712 - 20 points

Jack Young - 664611 - 30 points

The I want to be able to call methods like setPoints to change the point values for whatever the student selected is.

Here's the problem: How can I link the ArrayList together. If I have three ArrayLists, how does Java know what name, student id and points are associated together?

All the ArrayLists are stored in a class called Data.

Data data = new Data();

Also, all the ArrayLists in the Data class should be outputted to a file which will be loaded next time the app is opened.

I will try to answer any questions.

Comment: most likely, you need to create a class that has 3 fields  Name, Student ID and their points, and define a arrayList that has the type of the class. Basically, each elements of arrayList contain an object which includes what you want. And you will not end up with a lot of complication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a class which contain **3 data field**s as follows

> 1. Name
> 2. Student ID
> 3. their points

But not to forget, the class has to have other necessary elements of a class like:

> 1. Constructor
> 2. Overloaded Constructors if they are necessary
> 3. Accessors
> 4. Mutators

**Note**: For **accessing** each part of an object in your arrayList, you can use accessors. For **manipulating** each part of an object in your arrayList, you can use mustators.

After having such a class, you can define a arrayList that contain elements with type of class you have already define

Like:

```
List<Your Type of class > students = new ArrayList<Your Type of class>;
```

After `Java 7`, you can do

```
List<Your Type of class > students = new ArrayList<>;
```

which is diamond inference.

If you are looking for a specific id number in your arrayList, you can do something like:

```
public boolean findIdNumber(int idNumber){
    for(int i=0; i< students.size; i++)
          if(students.get(i).getID() == idNumber)
               return true;
          else
               return false;
}
```

**Warning**:

> what I have done are suggestions for you to be able to look for what you want smoother. You need to do necessary changes in order to comply what you were
>   asked to do

Comment: how could I say getPoints(int studentID) and have it search the ArrayList for the ID and return the point value associated with the student.

Comment: As I said, you gonna use your accessor to access to the part, if it is equal to what you are looking for , you do what you want to do , if it is not, you keep searching. if it is not clear , please lemee know

Comment: it shouldn't return a boolean. It should return an int with the point value.

Comment: @JacksonWelch what I did is a suggestion. You need to do necessary changes in order to comply what you were asked to do .

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a class named `Student`, and then declare an array/ArrayList of the Student type. Your `Student` class must have a constructor that sets the fields of an instance of the Student class (the created instance is now called an object).

So first create a Student class in the same package in which your other class is (the class in which your `main` method is):

```
public class Student {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String studentId;
    private int points;

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String studentId, int points) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.points = points;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public void setPoints(int points) {
        this.points = points;
    }        
}
```

Then in your `main` method or wherever you like, create a Hashmap to hold your Student objects. A map/hashmap is a collection just like an ArrayList to hold a set of objects. In your use case, it is better to use a hashmap because finding/retrieving a specific student object is much faster and easier when you use a hashmap.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // a map is a "key-value" store which helps you search items quickly 
        // (by only one lookup)
        // here you consider a unique value of each object as its 'key' in the map,
        // and you store the whole object as the value for that key.
        // that is why we defined Student as the second type in the following 
        // HashMap, it is the type of the "value" we are going to store
        // in each entry of this map. 
        Map<String, Student> students = new HashMap<String, Student>();

        Student john = new Student("John", "Doe", "401712", 20);
        Student jack = new Student("Jack", "Young", "664611", 30);

        students.put("401712", john);
        students.put("664611", jack);

        Student johnRetrieved = students.get("401712"); 
        // each hashmap has a get() method that retrieves the object with this 
        // specific "key". 
        // The following line retrieves the student object with the key "664611".
        Student jackRetrieved = students.get("664611");

        // set/overwrite the points "field" of this specific student "object" to 40
        johnRetrieved.setPoints(40);     
        int johnsPoints = johnRetrieved.getPoints(); 
        // the value of johnsPoints "local variable" should now be 40

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The classical object-oriented approach would be to create a Student class including name, ID and points and storing list of Student objects in a single ArrayList.

```
class Student{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private int points;

    public Student(String id, String, name, int points){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.points = points;
    }
}
..
ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

students.add(new Student(1, 'John Doe', 1000));

String id = students.get(0).id;
```